# Particle.js not showing on Django (JS and CSS not functioning)

Tags: django, particles

I don't know what im doing wrong but the particles wont display properly. Kinda new to django and I would like some insight over why this is happening. 
Note: This is an app called MUNFair within a project called djangoTrial1. 
HTML

```
{%load static%}
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.2.2/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{%static 'fair/particles.js' %}">
    </script>

    <div id="particles-js">
        <h1>Text to go here</h1>    
    </div>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'MunFair/static'),
]
```

Directory Path

```
+---djangoTrial1
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|           
+---MunFair
|   |   admin.py
|   |   apps.py
|   |   models.py
|   |   tests.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   views.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   

|   +---static
|   |   \---fair
|   |       |   .gitignore
|   |       |   bower.json
|   |       |   Fair.css
|   |       |   LICENSE.md
|   |       |   package.json
|   |       |   particles.js
|   |       |   particles.min.js
|   |       |   README.md
|   |       |   
|   |       \---demo
|   |           |   debug.log
|   |           |   index.html
|   |           |   particles.json
|   |           |   
|   |           +---css
|   |           |       style.css
|   |           |       
|   |           \---js
|   |               |   app.js
|   |               |   
|   |               \---lib
|   |                       stats.js
|   |                       
|   +---templates
|   |       debug.log
|   |       FairHome.html
```

I think the correct directory is being referenced since the server runs without issues.

Comment: If you inspect you're web page do you see if its loaded or are you getting an error? (Right click, inspect, console)

Comment: When i inspect I can see the code there, there no error but it still doesnt display the actual particle effect

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue? I am facing the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have debug = true in settings.py, or do manage.py collectstatic, also you can try loading it with cdn